# Keras: expected dense_5 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (60000, 10)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm running the following code on python 3.6:

```
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images = train_images.reshape((60000, 28, 28, 1)).astype('float')/255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28, 28, 1)).astype('float')/255
train_labels = ku.to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = ku.to_categorical(test_labels)
filepath = 'my_model_file.hdf5' # define where the model is saved
callbacks_list = [
        keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
            monitor = 'val_loss', # Use accuracy to monitor the model
            patience = 1 # Stop after one step with lower accuracy
        ),
        keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
            filepath = filepath, # file where the checkpoint is saved
            monitor = 'val_loss', # Don't overwrite the saved model unless val_loss is worse
            save_best_only = True # Only save model if it is the best
        )
]
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28, 28, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu', kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()
## Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

## Now fit the model
nr.seed(2356)
set_random_seed(2333)
history = model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=40, batch_size = 128, callbacks = callbacks_list, validation_data = (test_images, test_labels))  # Call backs argument here)
```

and get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_5 to have shape (None, 1) but got array with shape (60000, 10)
```

The previous posts I look talk about datalabel should be convert to categorical data but this is done. Actually most of the code is copy and past from tensor flow tutorial so it's little bit hard to see where things where wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Use loss functions categorical_crossentropy

> loss='categorical_crossentropy'

beacause your label was encoded at

> train_labels = ku.to_categorical(train_labels)

PS.
If your label are endcoded(one-hot encoded) use categorical_crossentropy
ex:

> [1,0,0]
>   [0,1,0]
>   [0,0,1]

But if your targets are integers, use sparse_categorical_crossentropy
ex:

> [1,2,3]

Comment: How about a little more background here or reasons that you feel this is the right approach?

Comment: If your label are endcoded(one-hot encoded) use categorical_crossentropy

But if your targets are integers, use sparse_categorical_crossentropy